# Which Talmudic chapter has the most Halachic references by number?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, jewish-books, number, statistics

Modern printings of the Talmud include Ein Mishpat glosses at the top outside corner of each page (for the most part). Which chapter reaches the highest number? I think I'd like to delve into that chapter; or share this factoid at a Shabbos dinner.

Comment: Probably first chapter of kiddushin which is the longest in general, and it's not like it has lots of aggadata or something non halachic